# New <updateManifestEntries> entries of webstart-maven-plugin breaks the application

Tags: java, jnlp, jar-signing, maven-jar-plugin, maven-webstart-plugin

As my JDK version upgraded to u45 now I get warnings about missing security information. So I used following security updates as part of webstart signing using webstart-maven-plugin

```xml
<plugin>
<groupId> org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-beta-4</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>jnlp-inline</goal>
            <!-- use jnlp, jnlp-inline or jnlp-single as appropriate -->
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <!--outputDirectory></outputDirectory -->
    <!-- not required?? -->
    <!-- Set to true to exclude all transitive dependencies. Default is 
        false. -->
    <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
    <!-- The path where the libraries are stored within the jnlp structure. 
        not required. by default the libraries are within the working directory -->
    <libPath>lib</libPath>
    <!-- resourcesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/jnlp/resources</resourcesDirectory -->
    <!-- default value -->
    <!-- JNLP generation -->
    <jnlp>
        <!-- default values -->
        <!-- inputTemplateResourcePath>${project.basedir}</inputTemplateResourcePath -->
        <!--inputTemplate>src/main/jnlp/template.vm</inputTemplate -->
        <!-- relative to inputTemplateResourcePath -->
        <outputFile>xxxx.template</outputFile>
        <!-- defaults to launch.jnlp -->
        <!-- used to automatically identify the jar containing the main class. -->
        <!-- this is perhaps going to change -->
        <mainClass>XXXXXX</mainClass>
    </jnlp>
    <!-- SIGNING -->
    <!-- defining this will automatically sign the jar and its dependencies, 
        if necessary -->
    <sign>
        ..................
    </sign>
    <!-- BUILDING PROCESS -->
    <pack200>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </pack200>
    <gzip>true</gzip>
    <!-- default force when pack200 false, true when pack200 selected 
        ?? -->
    <!-- causes a version attribute to be output in each jar resource 
        element, optional, default is false -->
    <outputJarVersions>true</outputJarVersions>
    <!--install>false</install -->
    <!-- not yet supported -->
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <updateManifestEntries>
        <Application-Name>cccccc</Application-Name>
        <Trusted-Library>true</Trusted-Library>
        <Permissions>all-permissions</Permissions> 
        <Codebase>*</Codebase>
        <Trusted-Only>true</Trusted-Only> 
    </updateManifestEntries>
</configuration>
```

Here

```xml
<updateManifestEntries>
<Application-Name>cccccc</Application-Name>
<Trusted-Library>true</Trusted-Library>
<Permissions>all-permissions</Permissions> 
<Codebase>*</Codebase>
<Trusted-Only>true</Trusted-Only> 
</updateManifestEntries>
```

breaks the application when it launches. Dependency injection not happening. I had to add updated manifest information even for Spring related jar.

I tried doing the same with

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But not seems working.

Appreciate your immediate reply as I have been trying this since last week

The issue is with webstart-maven-plugin (1.0-beta-4) whose

```
<updateManifestEntries>
                            <!--    <Permissions>all-permissions</Permissions> 
                                <Application-Name>catsvision</Application-Name>
                                <Trusted-Library>true</Trusted-Library>
                                <Codebase>*</Codebase>
                                <Trusted-Only>true</Trusted-Only>  -->
                            </updateManifestEntries>
```

not working as expected.

When I tried to do the same with

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                            <manifestFile>
                                src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
                                </manifestFile>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                                    <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>false</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

where MANIFEST.MF has following entry

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Application-Name: CATS Vision
Codebase: *
Trusted-Library: true
Trusted-Only: true
```

worked for me. But it was for a particular JAR. How can I update manifest entries for a bundle of JARs (I mean my webstart bundle)? Is there any plugin for it other than maven-webstart-plugin

Comment: When I tried this with maven-jar-plugin , permission issue resolved.
<manifestEntries>
<!-- <Application-Name>My App</Application-Name>--> Not worked - JAR corrupted after adding this entry and application failed to work as expected eventhough it's launched
<Permissions>all-permissions</Permissions> Worked
                                    <!--<Codebase>www.XXX.xom</Codebase>--> Not worked
                                </manifestEntries>

Answer (score 2):

This seems an open bug with maven-webstart-plugin

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWEBSTART-224

I resolved this issue:

1. Update the permission attributes using maven-antrun-plugin
2. Sign JARS using maven-jarsigner-plugin
3. Use maven-webstart-plugin just to create JNLP bundle, not for signing or anything else

Comment: codehaus is now down, I will try to find out the issue and solve it soon.